# How to calculate an 8 hour mean? (non-running average)

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate, intervals

I would like to calculate an average of 8 hour averages.

My approach: cut every 8 hours and then take the mean of each 8 hour segment. The second step is to get the mean of these 8 hour averages.

I would like some suggestions on how to create the 8 hour cuts using the data below.

First couple of rows of the data:

```
 PacificTime       UTC_Time         day    site_id O3_calibrated
 1:  7/5/2017 1:00  7/5/2017 8:00 7/5/2017 ACTV006  9.838518
 2:  7/5/2017 2:00  7/5/2017 9:00 7/5/2017 ACTV006  11.460619 
 3:  7/5/2017 3:00 7/5/2017 10:00 7/5/2017 ACTV006  11.888137
 4:  7/5/2017 4:00 7/5/2017 11:00 7/5/2017 ACTV006  10.371818
 5:  7/5/2017 5:00 7/5/2017 12:00 7/5/2017 ACTV006  6.759685
```

Data format:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  124304 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ PacificTime   : chr  "7/5/2017 1:00" "7/5/2017 2:00" "7/5/2017 3:00" 
 "7/5/2017 4:00" ...
 $ site_id       : chr  "ACTV006" "ACTV006" "ACTV006" "ACTV006" ...
 $ O3_calibrated : num  9.84 11.46 11.89 10.37 6.76 ...
```

The code I am trying to use is to first create the 8 hour averages, then take the mean of these 8 hour averages.

```
actapdata %>% mutate (o8 = cut(PacificTime, breaks = 8 )) %>%
  group_by (o8, site_id) %>%
   summarise(o8_avg = mean(O3_calibrated))

  o3_avg <- actapdata %>% 
     group_by(site_id) %>% 
     summarise(o3 =  mean(o8_avg, na.rm=T) )
```

Comment: You need to convert the column PacificTime into a date/time format with the `as.POSIXct` function.  Once you have a date/time object set your `breaks = 8 hours` and then your code should work.

Comment: I also like `mutate (o8 = lubridate::floor_date(PacificTime, "8 hours"))` for this sort of thing.